# Vertical Dropdown menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a drop down menu using ul and li.
My actual problem is, when I click on letter "A", it opens menu "A" and menu "B" at the same time, the same problem happens when I click on letter B.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a class="clickto">A </a>
  </li>
  <li class="show" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">AAA </a>
  </li>
  <li class="show" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">AAA </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a class="clickto">B </a>
  </li>
  <li class="show" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">BBB </a>
  </li>
  <li class="show" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#">BBBB </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".clickto").click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
    $(".show").slideUp(500);
    $(this).removeClass("clicked")
  }else{
    $(".show").slideDown(500);
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  }
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsJoe/qby3x1ya/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `$('.show')` will match all elements with the `show` class on the page - which means both menus.

You can fix this by having a more specific selector, which finds the closest `nav` class then finds the `show` class within that.

```
$(".clickto").click(function() {
  var $show = $(this).closest('.nav').find('.show');
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    $show.slideUp(500);
    $(this).removeClass("clicked")
  } else{
    $show.slideDown(500);
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9cauyora/